# Local repository directories disappeared?

Tags: git, github

I'm pretty new to Git, and recently started to use branches, but I don't think I have the concepts down, and now I'm running into problems.

Basically, I created a devel branch, and am creating feature branches to merge small changes into devel. I deleted some files in the feature branches, and thus in devel, but now I realized I want them again. They presumably are still in master, as I can see them online on GitHub, but when I ran the command "git checkout master", many directories and files have disappeared. I really have no clue why this has happened. How do I fix the problem?

EDIT: Is it possible for changes in other branches to cause problems when I switch back to the master branch? I feel like the master branch should have remained the same as before.

EDIT 2: It looks like the deletions happened when I was working on a feature branch and did "git checkout devel" - I was in a deep subdirectory when I ran this command, and for whatever reason there were a bunch of "D ... file" lines outputted, ending with "Switched to branch 'devel'" In fact, this continues to happen as I switch between branches.

Comment: Can you give us an example breakdown of your directory structure before and after you did the checkout?  Were these files added and committed in the development branches, before you checked out master?

Comment: @Glu what are you pointing by saying many directories and files disappeared? Are those files and directories present in master in github?

Comment: @mithun_ghose Yes, they are present in master in github.

Comment: Can you please attach a screen shot of directories and files present in your local repo and the github master branch.

Comment: @roelofs I'm not sure exactly how to explain, I think everything looks fine on github, but on my local repository everything is messed up. I wouldn't like to screenshot that because it's private. In github, the directory I'm talking about has 3 directories and 8 files, while locally it just has 1 directory and 0 files, its parent directory has a subdirectory which I want in devel, but not in master. It's all a mess.

Comment: So, wait, did those directories disappear on your local repository, when you moved from devel branch to master branch, but the directories are present on the github repository?  Did you remove anything in your local master branch, but haven't pushed to the remote (github) yet?  Or did you add things in your devel branch, that then disappeared when you switched back to master?  We really need more information.

Comment: @roelofs Sorry for being unclear. When I moved from the devel branch back to the master branch, the directories disappeared on my local depository. They are still present on the github repository. I didn't do anything in my local master branch before or after switching back.

Comment: If you didn't remove items in master, can't you just do a git pull?

Comment: @roelofs It says "Already up-to-date" when I do git pull for some reason. It doesn't give me back the files that are on Github that aren't on my local repo.

Comment: @roelofs Would "git clone" solve the issue? It doesn't explain to me why this happened, but it would be a fix, right?

Comment: @mithun_ghose I added some extra info, although maybe not exactly what you wanted, do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yap git clone will work if you want to clone the whole project again.

Comment: You need to git clone into a seperate directory though.  I'll add an answer below if you want to 'reset' the current checkout.

Comment: @Glu please upvote or accept answer that you have got working or think help you along the way. It is a way that appreciates the people who have tried to help you.

Comment: @mithun_ghose I upvoted both of your answers, but since my reputation is so low, it isn't being shown. I don't know whose answer to accept since I really didn't figure out what happened, and just git clone'd into a separate directory.

Answer (score 0):

If your current checkout of `master` appears to be corrupt, you can try to reset it to either `HEAD`, or a specific commit, using the following:

`git reset --hard HEAD`

This will do a hard reset to the last known commit, and any working copy changes in your branch (which it does not appear you have) will be lost.

If it still does not fix your issue, you may have to look into doing a new clone into a new directory.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to reset.

You can see all of your commits and from there you can know your last good commit where everything was ok, by invoking the command

```
git log
```

After that you can reset to your known good commit by invoking

```
git reset --hard commit_number
```

But be careful it will remove all current files created after that commit.